# What are "kakikaeji"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [kakikaeji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kakikaeji) that is only applied to a single question - [On the replacing of kanji made obsolete in the 1946 reforms with similar-looking kanji.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/531/3437).

I am not sure what this tag is supposed to be for - it has no tag wiki; the only search results for "kakikaeji" (romanized) point back to this site; my IME refuses to give any conversions for かきかえじ that contain 字; and I cannot find any uses of 書き換え字, which is what I presume are the correct kanji for this term.

Comment: It's Kaji's tag.  He added it when he answered the question.  Maybe you can find something there.

Comment: @Kaji Help! Do you have more information on 書換字? I can't find the term in any dictionary (which sort of makes me wonder if it will prove very useful).

Answer (score 2):

If you search for the term without okurigana you'll get some hits (the occasional joys of Japanese orthography...).

Original source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakikae#Kakikae *(It's first mentioned in the 4th paragraph of the Tōyō Kanji section of the article, but the highlighted section provides more detail.)*

Japanese sources:

- [http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/意符書換字](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%84%8F%E7%AC%A6%E6%9B%B8%E6%8F%9B%E5%AD%97)
- [http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/同音の漢字による書きかえ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8C%E9%9F%B3%E3%81%AE%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88)

I'll see about drafting a tag wiki entry for it over the weekend.  It's significant because it's a different type of script reform from the Shinjitai simplifications.

Comment: The second source doesn't mention かきかえじ, only いふしょかんじ (意符書換字).  The first and third sources mention かきかえ, but not かきかえじ.   The third also mentions だいようじ（代用字）.  So it seems like *kakikae* or *daiyōji* might be more appropriate as tags than *kakikaeji*, which doesn't appear in your sources.  Both 書きかえ and 代用する／代用字／代用語 seem to be in use, and in particular we can see 書きかえ used by the [Agency for Cultural Affairs](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kakuki/03/pdf/doon.pdf).